# How to handle validation on invalid has_many children when parent is already saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these two classes:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :article_tags
end
class ArticleTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, format: /\A\p{Alpha}*\z/
end
```

Now I add an *invalid* tag to my article:

**This works:**

```
item = Item.new
item.tags << Tag.new(name: '1&+')
item.valid?                         # Returns false
```

**But this does *not:***

```
item = Item.find(params[:id])
item.tags << Tag.new(name: '1&+')   # Exception here!
```

The reason is that - if the item already exists in the database - the `<<` method automatically saves the new tag using `save!`.

What I want is the item to have a validation error instead, just like in the first case.

Can this be achieved? Can I disable the automatic saving in the `<<` method?

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to be caused by the `has_many through` association. A simple `has_many` association does not suffer from the same problem.

Calling the `<<` method ultimately fails in `has_many_through_association.rb`:

```
def concat(*records)
  unless owner.new_record?
    records.flatten.each do |record|
      raise_on_type_mismatch(record)
      record.save! if record.new_record?                 # Exception here!
    end
  end
  super
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything you need to worry about :)

You last line of code will pass. There is no problem because the tag object is not persist - It's `new`.

The item is in database, but the new "tag" object is not. It's in memory only. The validation rules will only be triggered when you trying to save the object into db.

Try this in console:

```
> item = Item.find(params[:id])
> item.tags << Tag.new(name: '1&+') 
> item.tags[0]
#=> #<Tag:abcd0123> {
#  id: nil
#  name: '1&+'
#  ....
# } 
> item.tags[0].save!
#=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed
```

Comment: It seems that I have over-simplified my question. You are right, that code works, but not if I'm using `has_many through: ...`. I've updated my question.

Comment: @DanielRikowski, I havn't tested has_many through in console but I double you conclusion. Wherever `save!` is called, the object must go through validation and it should be able to throw an error in `concat`